# table with closeable? columns

Tags: tablecolumn

Is there a jquery table element widget which allows you to remove certain columns by clicking an  'x' icon? I'd previously used a custom tab interface I found online only to find out after I'd implemented most everything that I could've used jquery tabs (sigh) and would like to avoid similar situation.

Looking for something similar to [this](http://www.hospitalcompare.hhs.gov/hospital-compare.aspx#cmprTab=0&cmprID=210002%2C210013%2C210008&stsltd=%20MD&loc=Baltimore%2C%20MD&lat=39.2903848&lng=-76.61218930000001&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite simply yourself. If you search on stackoverflow for "jquery remove table column" you will find many answers. Here is a "plugin": http://jquery-howto.blogspot.se/2009/05/remove-nth-table-column-jquery-plugin.html

Using this function, create your x-icon element with id="x_element" and add some javascript:

```
$('#x_element').click({
  $('#table_id').removeCol(2);
});
```

Comment: uh! 'removeable' columns! that's the word i was looking for. thanks! this is exactly what i was looking for!